# Search elements in a list in another list and check each element exist or not

Tags: python, list

I have 2 lists as

```
x = ["abc", "def", "ghi"]

y = ["ggg", "hhh", "abc", "yyy", "ttt", "uuu", "ooo". "def", "www", "xxx"]
```

I am trying to create a new lists called `match`

when there is a match of values of list `x` in `y` the `match` list should get appended if not present then it should be appended with Not Found.

Like in the above case the `match` list should be

```
match = ["Present", "Present", "Not Found"]
```

I tried different logics but am not getting the right answer, below is what I tried

```
match = []
for j in range(len(x)):
        for k in range(len(y)):
            if x[j]==y[k]:
                match.append("Present")
            else:
                pass
        match.append("Not Found")
```

Another way

```
or j in range(len(x)):
        for k in range(len(y)):
            if x[j]==y[k]:
                match.append("Present")
            else:
                match.append("Not found")
```

Another way I tried is

```
for k in range(len(x)):
        for j in range(len(y)):
            if x[k]==y[j]:
                match.append("Present")

  
    for k in range(len(x)):
        for j in range(len(y)):
            if x[k]==y[j]:
                pass
            else:
                match.append("Not Found")
```

I believe the logic is simple but I ma not getting around it. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update** add memory for `x` to search each `x` one-time to get better run-time.

```
mem_x = {i: 'Not Found' for i in set(x)}
set_y = set(y)
for k,v in mem_x.items():
    if k in set_y:
        mem_x[k] = 'Present'
        
match = [mem_x[i] for i in x]
print(match)
```

**OLD**

You can use `set(y)` for getting better performance in searching and then search each value of `x` exists in `set(y)` or not.

```
x = ["abc", "def", "ghi"]

y = ["ggg", "hhh", "abc", "yyy", "ttt", "uuu", "ooo", "def", "www", "xxx"]

set_y = set(y)

match = ['Present' if i in set_y else 'Not Fount' for i in x]
print(match)
```

Output:

```
['Present', 'Present', 'Not Fount']
```

Or create an empty `list` and `append` in it. *(But the second approach without `list.append()` is a better approach.)*

```
match = []
set_y = set(y)
for i in x:
    if i in set_y:
        match.append('Present')
    else:
        match.append('Not Fount')
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, This is so much clear now!

Comment: @StevenRumbalski, I add a better approach with memo for x, see this ;)

Comment: @sahasrara62,  I add a better approach with a memo for x, see this ;)

Answer (score 2):

As @I'mahdi said, function set() can solve your problem perfectly. Actually there are many bulit-in functions, try to be familiar with them.

As to your impletation:

1. This will always add a "Not Found" to match list, you should continue when match completes; len(match) = len(x) + len(present)

```
match = []
for j in range(len(x)):
        for k in range(len(y)):
            if x[j]==y[k]:
                match.append("Present")
            else:
                pass
        match.append("Not Found")
```

2.This will lead to too many "Not found", because every unmatch will be recorded.(len(match) = len(x) * len(y))

```
or j in range(len(x)):
        for k in range(len(y)):
            if x[j]==y[k]:
                match.append("Present")
            else:
                match.append("Not found")
```

3.The same as 2.

```
    for k in range(len(x)):
        for j in range(len(y)):
            if x[k]==y[j]:
                match.append("Present")

  
    for k in range(len(x)):
        for j in range(len(y)):
            if x[k]==y[j]:
                pass
            else:
                match.append("Not Found")
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the issue with my code blocks, I wil keep this in mind

Answer (score 1):

I'll consider only your second try:

```
for j in range(len(x)):
        for k in range(len(y)):
            if x[j]==y[k]:
                match.append("Present")
            else:
                match.append("Not found")
```

By putting `match.append("Not found")` in the else branch then`"Not found"` will be appended to `match` for each item `y[k]` that is
different than `x[j]`.  For example for `"abc"` you will insert to
`match` successively, `"Not found"`, `"Not found"`, `"Present"`, `"Not found"` and so on.

The thing is that you can only conclude that the item is Not found
after the inner loop terminates.  Then you will to check if
`"Present"` has been put in your list.  For this you can use a boolean
variable initialised to `False` and set to `True` if the item is
present.  This gives:

```
for j in range(len(x)):
        found = False
        for k in range(len(y)):
            if x[j]==y[k]:
                match.append("Present")
                found = True
                break
        if not found:
            match.append("Not found")
```

The `break` statement is there to avoid looping on remaining items if the `x[j]` has been found in `y` and also to avoid putting `"Present"` several times in the list if `x[j]` appears several times in `y`.

Comment: Thank you, I get it now what was wrong with my set of code